# sqoop date to impala timestamp

Tags: mysql, hadoop, timestamp, sqoop, impala

I am importing data with sqoop from MySQL to hdfs as parquet file where it is used by Impala. There is a problem with conversion of MySQL DATE type to Impala TIMESTAMP.

Impala error message when executing `compute stats table` or `select *` is:

```
File 'hdfs://....parquet'
has an incompatible type with the table schema for column 'day'.
Expected type: INT32.  Actual type: INT64
```

Changing data type of the day column to BIGINT or STRING leaves the error msg same.

Even when I change day column type in Impala to STRING and set --map-column-java "day=String" (also tried day=Integer and Long) in sqoop I get:

```
Expected type: INT32.  Actual type: BYTE_ARRAY in Impala
```

I also tried setting mapDateToTimestamp=false (and true) in jdbc connection string but with no effect

What is the way to convert MySQL DATE to Impala TIMESTAMP with sqoop when using parquet file(note that I am not using AVRO)?

(sqoop version I use is 1.4.5-cdh5.3.3)
Sqoop command looks like this:

```
sqoop import
--connect jdbc:mysql://adress/db
--username name
--password pass
--table tableName
--target-dir dir
--as-parquetfile -m 1
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

edit: I tried converting SQL Date with

```
--query "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(day, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

but Impala sees it as INT64 and expects INT96. So another question is how to convert it to INT96?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only way is to use `--map-column-java "day=String"` and either have that column as STRING in Impala and use `cast()` function for queries with day or use temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

did you try INT96 ?
also I think you wont able to convert the  TINYINT, SMALLINT column to BIGINT

Comment: I am not sure how to use that in --map-column-java "day=???", btw. String produces BYTE_ARRAY in Impala

Comment: Indeed. Impala uses INT96 for TIMESTAMP but sqoop doesnt use that mapping (only to INT64) and java doesn't support INT96 so there is no way to override the mapping

Answer (score 0):

Usally what we follow is while we import from scoop or other external system all datatype will be defaulted to string (landing) after landing we will use

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(<datecol>,yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

To convert to impala specific timestamp